# Is re-authentication necessary?

Tags: usability

Is re-authentication necessary? If you login to a website, then want to change your username, password, or email address, is it necessary for you to have to login again?

Comment: Yes, it's necessary if you make it necessary. This is a question of security and how valuable is the data regardless of user comfort. As it stands your question is a tad bit off-topic because it doesn't sound like you've addressed the security concerns of your app. A more appropriate question would have been something like "We require our users to re-authenticate after changing their credentials, should we send them back to the main login page or use a modal AJAX window and let them re-authenticate like that?"

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit for discussing the pitfalls of not forcing re-authentication.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the time saved and lack of annoyance is not worth the risk of having someone who shouldn't be on the user's profile go in and just have free range to change whatever they see fit. What I would do in this situation isn't have them log back in, but force the user to type in their password again in order to save any profile changes.

Answer (score 1):

Re-authentication helps to mitigate the risks of accepting a change that you can't be sure was intended by your actual user. Here are some vulnerabilities if you don't implement re-authentication:

- Imagine your actual user Alice has logged in, but went into another room briefly. In the meantime, malicious Mary changes their password. Alice won't discover this until she logs off and back on again. In the meantime, Mary can use or share Alice's compromised credentials.
- Alice has logged in, and your system places an authorization cookie on their system valid for 30 days. During this period, Alice leaves the system unattended for a few minutes. Mary goes into your app on Alice's system. The stored cookie logs her in automatically. Mary changes the email address on Alice's profile and exits your app. Later, she can use your *"I've forgotten my password"* mechanism to force a password reset with a new temporary password being sent to the new email address. She uses this to take over Alice's identity on your system. When Mary does a bad thing, Alice argues that this is your responsibility because of the known weakness of your process.
- Alice wants to do a bad thing. She understands that you can't prove identity following a password reset, so she simulates the behavior of a fake "Mary". Once she has established this history, she does the bad thing. If anyone tries to blame Alice, she can repudiate responsibility because your process makes it so easy for someone else to have done the bad thing pretending to be her.

You might find the book "Security and Usability" (O'Reilly 2007) a good starting point for further reading, particularly chapters 2 and 32 by Angela Sasse.